# How do I get my e-mail address off my Folders GUI?

Tags: directory, email

I know this is trivial, but I don't like it and I will learn something.
How do I get my e-mail off of the folders gui?
[Email in folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggpKW.png)

Comment: Place pointer on it, right click, select `Remove`

Comment: Nope, that don't work. BTW I'm using 22.10

Comment: First of all, what does it do if you click on it? In the meanwhile, if I may guess, did you set up some remote file storage that you access with that e-mail address? Like google drive?

Comment: How did the address get there in the first place? Where did you enter it?

Comment: If its your google drive, unmount it and deselect it from `Settings > Online Accounts > Google`

Comment: see "online accounts" "google".

Comment: 1. It is not mounted and I can't get it to mount. 2. I just installed 22.10 and it showed up. 3. THAT DID IT, thanks.

Comment: @Rinzwind in Nautilus' preferences? Accessed through the Nautilus window's hamburger icon? Or rather, the main Ubuntu settings app (usually in the dock)?

Comment: no programs .... it is added when you add google in "online accounts"